# Provide different container for every user using AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to launch different containers for every user, so that they won't interfere with others work. Is it possible on ECS Fargate?

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear re what you would like to exactly achieve. If you intend to launch n containers inside a single Fargate task that is possible (to a certain extent, up to 10). However this isn't really how it usually work because the task is the atomic unit and unit of scale usually. So anything you are trying to do that requires a hard bind for "user" to container would ideally better served by a "user" to task (w/ 1 container) model. If your containers are super tiny there may be some better efficiencies in running more inside a task (which has a less flexible granularity) but this needs to be compatible with the operations you intend to run against those tasks/containers.